# Sequencing inside groups and w.r.t. value in R

Tags: r, for-loop, replace

I have a dataset with columns "Seq" and "N" with different values (example below). I want to insert an ID number based on the "N" change as well as for a particular value of "Seq" column i.e.3 (if last row has 3 as Seq, then change Serial to next number). I am using a for loop for that. But because of large dataset it takes a lot of time. Is there any other way.

Example of dataset:

```
S    N    Seq 
1  BAC     1  
2  BAC     2  
3  BAC     3   
3  BAC     2   
4  ABC     1   
5  ABC     3      
6  ABC     3   
6  BGC     1
```

Example of what i need:

```
S    N    Seq  Serial
1  BAC     1     1
2  BAC     2     1  #updated row
3  BAC     3     1
3  BAC     2     2
4  ABC     1     3
5  ABC     3     3   
6  ABC     3     4   #updated row(getting 3 only)
6  BGC     1     5
```

This is the for loop i am using:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(hjk1)){
  hjk1$Serial[1]=1 
  if(hjk1$N[i]!=hjk1$N[i-1])
    hjk1$Serial[i]<-hjk1$Serial[i-1]+1
  else
    if(hjk1$Seq[i-1]=3
    hjk1$Serial[i]<-hjk1$Serial[i-1]+1
  else
    hjk1$Serial[i]<-hjk1$Serial[i-1]
}
```

I need a replacement for this for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a combination of `paste` and `match` with `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
v1 <- with(df1, paste(N, na.locf(replace(Seq, Seq==3, NA))))
df1$Serial <- match(v1, unique(v1))
df1$Serial
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
```

---

Or another option is `factor`

```
df1$Serial <- as.integer(factor(v1, levels = unique(v1)))
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Seq1 = replace(Seq, Seq ==3, NA)) %>% 
   fill(Seq1) %>% 
   unite(N_Seq, N, Seq1, remove = FALSE) %>%
   mutate(Serial = match(N_Seq, unique(N_Seq))) %>% 
   select(-Seq1, -N_Seq)
#   S   N Seq Serial
# 1 1 BAC   1      1
# 2 2 BAC   3      1
# 3 3 BAC   2      2
# 4 4 ABC   1      3
# 5 5 ABC   3      3
# 6 6 BGC   1      4
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, we can do

```
df1$Serial <- with(df1,  cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(Seq==3)< 0)|!duplicated(N)))
df1$Serial
#[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4
```

#### Update2

```
df1$Serial <- with(df1, cumsum(!duplicated(cbind(c(0, cumsum(Seq[-length(Seq)]==3)), N))))
df1$Serial
#[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(S = 1:6, N = c("BAC", "BAC", "BAC", "ABC", "ABC", 
 "BGC"), Seq = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("S", "N", 
 "Seq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
###Update

df1<- rbind(df1,list(7,"BAC",2),list(8,"ABC",3)) 
df1<- df1[c(1,7,2,3,4,8,5,6),]
```

Comment: with the paste function, it is forming all the factors with each unique value of N and Seq combination, so the Serial Number I am getting is 1 2 3 4 5. Also if the combination of v1 is getting repeated it is giving it the same serial number, which I dont want

Comment: @IshanJuneja   Based on your example, I am getting `1 1 2 3 3 4` as you showed in the expected output

Comment: The output for v1 for you is like this?: BAC 3; ABC 3. Because I am getting v1 as: BAC 1; BAC 3, BAC2, ABC 1, ABC 3, BGC 1. Because of which it is assigning different Serial to every value

Comment: @IshanJuneja  I used the data (i updated in my post) and it gives exactly the same expected output as you showed

Comment: df1<-rbind(df1,list(7,"BAC",2),list(8,"ABC",3))  ;
df1<-df1[c(1,7,2,3,4,8,5,6),]
Just run these two lines after defining df1. You will see the difference. I want the serial number to change only if N changes or previous entry in Seq is 3

Comment: Thnak you so much . But still the problem is if in two consecutive rows: 3 is repeated in Seq, it needs to change the Serial. But it is not. In this example. See rows with N as ABC and Seq as 3.(row-6 &7)

Comment: @IshanJuneja  Please update your post with your expected output and new input.  It is not clear

Comment: @IshanJuneja  Updated the post again.

Comment: Thank you so much. Got exactly what I needed